# Using DXF files in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: qgis, dxf, illustrator, qgis-2.18

I updated from QGIS 2.0 to 2.18 i November, but it seemes to have caused problems with the dxf-exportation to adobe illustrator. The files from the newer version causes illustrator to "hang". The new files are about double the size of the old ones, but it should still not be too much for illustrator.

Is this a common problem with the 2.18-version?

Is there something I can do about it?

Is it recommandable to use another coding when I export the dxf, for example?

Now, I just use the default settings. Or should I just go back to the older qgis-version again?

Comment: Probably you need read more about this functionality: https://www.qgis.ch/en/projects/dxf-export

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't see where that page answers my question... I have experience with dxf-export from the 2.0-version, it's just that it doesn't work that well anymore in the 2.18...

Comment: you can try to remove the background fill and remove de unusued block for reduce size for example.

Comment: By "background fill" you mean the map in the background? I have allready done that; I'm only exporting the necessary  layers.